# Automatically restart USB audio device after return from standby

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-audio, devcon

I have a speaker system with a built in USB audio interface connected to my PC.
When the PC returns from standby, audio output is not working, even though the device is shown as audio output.

To get audio output again, I have to manually select another source than USB on the speaker system, and then switch back to USB.

I'd like to automate this on my Windows 10 system, so that after logon the USB device is automatically disconnected and reconnected.

I understand that this can be done using the Task Scheduler and a batch file that runs devcon.exe from the SDK, but when I enter "devcon disable "USB\VID_154E&PID_1004"" it demands a reboot.

"devcon restart" demands a reboot, too.

Is there a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try below setting to keep USB root hub to stay on during windows sleep mode.

1. On your keyboard, press the Windows **key + X** and select **Control Panel**.
2. Click **Hardware and Sound**, then click **Power Options**.
3. Click **Change plan settings** for the plan you want to change.
4. Click **Change advanced power settings**.
5. Click the **plus sign (+)** next to “USB settings” and “USB selective suspend setting” to expand the options and change the setting to **Disabled**.
6. Click **OK** to apply the setting.

Note: You may need to disconnect and re-connect your USB device after applying these settings to re-establish the connection.