Why is my wired USB keyboard not working properly anymore after standby?
My system…

Keyboard: HP Premium USB (cable)
OS: Windows 11
Port: USB 2

How to reproduce…

Enter Windows standby mode
Resume Windows
In the first few minutes, the keyboard still works fine
However, after a few minutes, the special characters (¦, @, #, ...) that need the ALT Cntrl key stop working

What I have tried…

Unpluging the keyboard USB cable and reconnect it (issue persists)
Restarting Windows "solves" the issue
Disabling selective USB suspension mode (issue persists)
Restarting USB device (issue persists)

Current solution…
I managed to set up an AutoHotkey script, that solves this issue for the most used characters in most scenarios, but there are input fields where AHK does not work either:
<^>!2::Send {ASC 64} ; @
<^>!3::Send {ASC 35} ; #

Is there a better way to solve this issue?
I first thought it was due to my old PC and/or Windows 10. But now, since I just got a brand new PC with Windows 11, the issue still persists.
Windows Support couldn't solve the issue.

Appears to be a known issue: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/usb-port-may-stop-working-after-you-remove-or-insert-a-usb-device-1eaf82a6-04b1-2604-f096-2345d9c215ef . Try restarting USB controller. Also check Power Options: disable Selective USB Suspend in Advanced settings. If that works, I'll make this an answer.

@DrMoishePippik Ah, I remember to have tried the selective USB energy setting with Windows 10 way back, but it still doesn't work with Windows 11 (just tested). However, what's interesting is, that in the first few minutes after resuming standby the keyboard still works. It seems to be only after after some minutes (using it?) that the key stops working... - what do you mean by restarting USB controller? How can I do this (easily)?


Device Manager > Universal Serial Bus controllers, try selecting one, right-click, disable then enable (can be scripted, if ti works) 2. Human Interface Devices - same for each port.


@DrMoishePippik I restarted the USB Port of the keyboard using "USB Device Tree Viewer", did not work unfortunately. However, in the device manager, I can't restart the HID keyboard (I see it 3 times actually).

@DrMoishePippik I found out, that I can solve this issue by disabling the Wmpkeys Plugin which provides global hotkeys for (legacy) Windows Media Player... so this plugin seems to mess with the keyboard functionality somehow, but only after suspension. Can the plugin perhaps be fixed?

If you have the source code, i.e., contact the developer at https://sourceforge.net/projects/wmpkeys/, yes.

@DrMoishePippik Looks like there is not much hope for that, the issue was reported already in 2010 and is still open... https://sourceforge.net/p/wmpkeys/bugs/2/

@DrMoishePippik Although this issue might never be solved, I actually have a similar issue with my USB speaker (need to unplug them after standby mode). Since to know how to automate this, you might want to post your answer to my second issue here? https://superuser.com/questions/1614694/automatically-restart-usb-audio-device-after-return-from-standby
